# Are "how long" and "how much time" the same?

Tags: question-words

which one is correct, coming from a pupil:

> How long do we have for / to do the exercise?"

or:

> "How much time do we have for this?"

I think that in the first question, the verb "have" does not have a clear object, "long" being an adjective not a noun, whereas "time" is clearly the object of have in the second question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All your suggested sentences are equally correct and equally idiomatic.

> **How long** do we have for the exercise (*or* this exercise *or* this)?
>
> **How much time** do we have for the exercise?
>
> **How long** do we have to do the exercise?
>
> **How much time** do we have to do the exercise?

In the "how long" version, "long" actually isn't an adjective but an adverb. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/long) explains it as follows:

> **long** *adverb* (TIME)
>
> used to mean "(for) a long time", especially in questions and negative sentences:
>
> *Have you been waiting (for) **long**?*
>
> *I'm just writing a letter but it won't take **long**.*
>
> ***How long*** have you been in England?
>
> *Don't rush - take as **long** as you like.*